# refresh vf page,

Tags: visualforce

I want to refresh my form, but this code is not working, kindly suggest me to what to do.

```visualforce
<apex:page controller="my_controller">
<script>
Function resetValue()
{
    Var.getElementById("{!$Component.frm.name}");
    Name.value='';
}
</script>

<apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:outputLabel value="Name" />
    <apex:inputText value="{!getttt}" id="name"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Reset" onclick="resetValue();"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

```apex
public with sharing class my_controller {
    public string getttt{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: <apex:page controller="my_controller">
<script>
Function resetValue()
{
Var.getElementById("{!$Component.frm.name}");
Name.value='';
}
</script>
 
<apex:form id="frm">
 <apex:outputLabel value="Name" />
<apex:inputText value="{!getttt}" id="name"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Reset" onclick="resetValue();"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some Apex function to set your form value back:

```apex
public void reset() {
    getttt = '';
}
```

And action function to refresh the form:

```visualforce
<apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:outputLabel value="Name" />
    <apex:inputText value="{!getttt}" id="name"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Reset" reRender="frm" action="{!reset}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```